# Что-то не так как должно по задумке. Python

Tags: python

```
string_ = "This website is for losers LOL!"
def disemvowel(string_):
    size = len(string_)
    for i in range(size):
        if string_[i] == 'a' or 'i' or 'u' or 'e' or 'o' or 'O':
            string_.replace(string_[i], "")
    print(string_)
disemvowel(string_)
```

По задумке, если находится гласная буква то функцией replace() вырезаем ее из строки, но так не получается. По результату выводит изначальную полную строку

Comment: Метод replace возвращает новую строку, но вы её никуда не сохраняете, в итоге новая строка уничтожается и внутри string_ остаётся старая исходная строка

Comment: Indra опять на те же грабли? никогда не меняйте (удалять, добавлять) списки когда двигаетесь по ним, соберите второй список и замените им первый

Comment: А ещё классическая "проблема строчного or" тоже в наличии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О чем мы в предыдущих вопросах говорили

не меняйте строку идя по ней, создайте новую

```
string_ = "This website is for losers LOL!"

string_ = ''.join(letter for letter in string_ if letter not in 'aiueoO')

print(string_)
```

а можно через регулярные выражения:

```
import re

string_ = "This website is for losers LOL!"

string_1 = re.sub('[aiueoO]', '', string_)
```

Comment: Чем будет отличаться копия списка если действия будут те же?